# Why did the twitter API require you to use the internal user_id instead of screen_name?

Tags: api-design

I've searched around for an answer to this question for a while and I can't come up with an answer. I haven't done Twitter API stuff in a while so it may have changed but I believe that at some point you had to use the lookup functionality in the API to get the internal user_id and do subsequent work with the internal user_id instead of the screen_name. Does anyone know why this was the case?

I'm building an API and I'm wondering if it makes sense to ask the consumers of the API to always do lookup in order to determine my internal ids and force them to use them or support using something like a username or email address that the consumer may (or may not) already know.

Comment: Usernames & email addresses can change

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you need a user_id is because users are able to change their names and emails. In other words, username is not unique. If you have only username and API returns more than one user you will need to decide which one is yours.

Comment: If all you have is a screen name, how does doing a lookup first ensure that you're any better off?

Comment: This is the start of a very good answer, but could use a *lot* of extra information. Perhaps a small discussion of "data as a key" is in order here?